# How to display images from mysql DB using php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
   <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("incisive_epos_db");
    //$code=$_GET['id'];

     $sql="Select `name`,`price`,`image`,`cost`,`alert_quantity` from products WHERE id='10'";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if($result){
            echo "<table style=\"width:100%\">
                  <tr>
                     <td>Produc Name</td>
                     <td>Price</td>
                     <td>Image</td>
                     <td>Cost</td>
                     <td>Quantity</td>
                  </tr>";
            while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>".$r['name']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$r['price']."</td>";
                     echo "<td><td>";
                     echo "<td>".$r['cost']."</td>";
                     echo "<td>".$r['alert_quantity']."</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";
             }
                      echo "</table>";
         }else{
             echo "Not Found";

         }
    ?>
```

i just want to ask that how to display image from db, i was using this but now i am stuck that how to display image in proper way pl. give me appropriate solution thanks for your consideration in advance.

Comment: What format is your image column in? Is it a filepath? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

if you have stored the file path in your db then...

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$r['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r['price']."</td>";
    echo "<td><img src="$r['image']" alt="" width="?" height="?" /><td>"; //provide your path to the image tag
    echo "<td>".$r['cost']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$r['alert_quantity']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

also try using **[mysqli](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)** and **use php in html** (i.e)

```
<?
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $r['name'];?></td>
        <td><? echo $r['price'];?></td>
        <td><img src="<? echo $r['image'];?>" alt="" width="?" height="?" /><td> //provide your path to the image tag
        <td><? echo $r['cost'];?></td>
        <td><? echo $r['alert_quantity'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?}?>
```

check your file path through inspect element in browsers... Providing correct path will surely give you the result...

**things to do:**

1. upload image
2. store the image in a folder in your project
3. create a query to save the image name in to the database
4. fetch the image data into a image tag

**=>** to store a image in to a folder...

make sure you **enable security permission editable** through properties to the folder you are going to save the image

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["pic"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    $extention  =   str_replace("image/","",$_FILES["file"]["type"]);
    $filename   =   time().'.'.$extention;  //creates a unique filename with timestamp

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], dirname(__FILE__).'/img/temp/'.$filename );  // here "/img/temp/" is folder location

    $valueToBeStoredIntoDB = 'img/temp/'.$filename;  //value to be stored in to the DB


}
```

Comment: Can you tell me that where should i place image path and how? pl. Clearify syntactically if you can Thanks for your consideration?